# How do I tell Hibernate to not create a table for this Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework-1.x, nativequery

I'm using `SqlResultSetMapping` and the `Entity` annotations (SqlResultSetMapping requires an Entity with an Id) to tell Hibernate how to populate instances of `Foo` with native query results data.

Non-persisted entity:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "fooMapping", entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = Foo.class))
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    public Long row_id;
    public String name;
}
```

Native query:

```
String sql = "SELECT id AS row_id, friendlyName AS name FROM SomeTable"; 
Query q = JPA.em().createNativeQuery(sql, "fooMapping");
List<Foo> fooList = q.getResultList();
```

The problem is, a table called "Foo" gets created automatically for me (using Play! Framework in dev mode), but Foo is not a model and should not be persisted.

How do I instruct hibernate not to create this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@ConstructorResult` will work great once it's available for your persistence layer. Until then, there is a Hibernate-specific approach using an `org.hibernate.SQLQuery` and an `org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer` that does not depend on `@SqlResultSetMapping`. Because a POJO is populated, Hibernate finds no `@Entity` to automatically turn into a table.

Non-persisted POJO:

```
public class Foo {
    public Long row_id;
    public String name;
}
```

ResultTransformer:

```
public static class FooResultTransformer implements ResultTransformer {

    @Override
    public List transformList(List list) { return list; }

    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
        List<String> aliasList = Arrays.asList(aliases);
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.row_id = ((Number) getValue(tuple, aliasList, "row_id", 0L))
            .longValue();
        foo.name = (String) getValue(tuple, aliasList, "name", null);
        return foo;
    }

    private static Object getValue(Object[] tuple, List<String> aliases,
            String field, Object defaultValue)
    {
        // unchecked for berevity
        if (tuple[aliases.indexOf(field)] == null) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        return tuple[aliases.indexOf(field)];
    }

}
```

Native SQLQuery:

```
String sql = "SELECT id AS row_id, friendlyName AS name FROM SomeTable";
Session session = JPA.em().unwrap(Session.class);
SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery(sql);

q.setResultTransformer( new FooResultTransformer() );
List<Foo> fooList = q.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't easy...

If you are using JPA 2.1 support for @ConstructorResult (seems there's only support in hibernate 4.3.0.Beta2 so you might not be using), you can use @ConstructorResult as follows:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="fooMapping", 
  classes={ 
    @ConstructorResult(targetClass=Foo.class, columns={
        @ColumnResult(name="row_id", type=Integer.class),
        @ColumnResult(name="name", type=String.class)
    })
  }
)

public class Foo {

    public Long row_id;
    public String name;

    public Foo(Long rowId, String name) {
    ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Looking forward to this; I'm going to hold out for an answer that works on JPA 2.0 or non-beta Hibernate.